# How to address a Comparator of a class in external generic method?

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I'm looking into how to use comparators to perform comparisons based on different fields.
So I created a class `Event`, which contains two Comparators.

```
class Event {
    int x, y;
    boolean isLeft;
    int index;

    Event(int x, int y, boolean isLeft, int index) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.isLeft = isLeft;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable> T[] quickSort(T[] a, int fst, int last, Comparator<T> comp) {
        int left = fst;
        int right = last;
        int middle = (last + fst) / 2;
        T x = a[middle];

        do {
            while (comp.compare(a[left], x) < 0) left++;
            while (comp.compare(a[right], x) > 0) right--;
            if (left <= right) {
                T temp = a[right];
                a[right] = a[left];
                a[left] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        } while (left <= right);

        if (left < last) {
            quickSort(a, left, last, comp);
        }
        if (fst < right) {
            quickSort(a, fst, right, comp);
        }

        return a;
    }

    static class XComparator implements Comparator<Event> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
            return (e1.x < e2.x) ? -1 : (e1.x > e2.x) ? 1 : (e1.y < e2.y) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    static class YComparator implements Comparator<Event> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
            return (e1.y < e2.y) ? -1 : (e1.y > e2.y) ? 1 : (e1.x < e2.x) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I pass the Comparator to a generic method of another class. A conflict of generic types I provide for `value` & `current.value`, and Comparator, is following:

> 'compare(Event, Event)' in 'Event.YComparator' cannot be applied to '(T, T)'

```
Node Rec(Node current, T value, Event.YComparator comp) {
        if (current == null) {
            size++;
            current = new Node(value);
            return current;
        }

        else if (comp.compare(value, current.value) < 0) {
            current.leftChild = Rec(current.leftChild, value, comp);
        } else if(comp.compare(value, current.value) > 0) {
            current.rightChild = Rec(current.rightChild, value, comp);
        } else {
            return current;
        }
```

But I can't find a solution, because Comparators are specific and should be tied to a class (they use its' fields).

I need any insight on this issue.

Comment: You need to use a generic comparator which takes a `method reference` or `lambda` which acts as a key extractor to be used for the comparisons.  Take a look at the `Comparator` interface source code included with the `JDK`, usually in `src.zip` to see how it is written.  Or just use the one included in the `JDK`.

Comment: Note: There's not really a need to check the `src.zip` which may or may not be present - it is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Comparator.java)

Comment: You declared `T extends Comparable` but Event doesn't implement Comparable so it isn't a suitable T.

Comment: @DavidJones thank you, turns out I didn't need generic type T to implement Comparable in this case

Answer (score 0):

I find your design somewhat confusing and overly complicated. So here are some suggestions.

- Define a `QuickSort` class that has a `static quickSort` method.
- Define a `Node` class (or record) that has the data types on which to sort.  Doing it this way makes it easier to specify multiple Comparator options and also allows the quick sort to be used for a list of Nodes that have different values and types to be sorted.
- First, get you `quickSort` working with no specified comparator.
- Then, get it working using a comparator from the `Comparator interface`. Try different options such as `reverseOrder()`, `thenComparing()`, `etc`.

Unless you have to implement your own comparator, you can stop here.  Otherwise, since everthing works, you can focus on your comparators which greatly limits where any developmental errors would originate.

I would start with something like the following:

```
record Node<T>(T data1, T data2) {
}

class QuickSort {
    public static <T> void quickSort(Node<T>[] nodes, int low, int high, 
                Comparator<Node<T>> comp) { //initially, comp can be ignored.
  
}
```

Comment: You can do that.  But you will need to make the `Node` array `Node<T>[]`  And the compare method I wrote won't work because type `T` may not be able to compare using `<, >, or ==`.  I would also recommend using a `List<Node<T>>` over an array as generic arrays don't work well with Java (they work but they can be messy).

Comment: I updated my answer to make it generic.  Type T refers to the payload on which you  are sorting.